# http 404 error when trying to call web api controller action method from .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-identity

I am getting Http 404 error on button click when i inspect element in browser.

There is a wallpost.js file in Scripts folder containing logic for knockout, client side view model and data- binding etc.
In this file, reference to the WallPost Api controller is given like this---

```
  var postApiUrl = '/api/WallPost/', commentApiUrl = '/api/Comment/';
```

and on my view page, there is a container for posting and commenting something like this--

```
    <div class="publishContainer">
<textarea class="msgTextArea" id="txtMessage" data-bind="value: newMessage, jqAutoresize: {}" style="height:3em;" placeholder="what's on your mind?"></textarea> 
<input type="button" data-url="/Wall/SavePost" value="Share" id="btnShare" data-bind="click: addPost"/>
```

now, references to script folder js files are given like this---

```
  @section scripts{
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.autosize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/wallpost.js"></script>
  }
```

First thing i want to clear that autosize.js is working fine on textarea so, i think path to wallpost.js file is correct as it is similar to autosize.js file.
Now, the problem is i am unable to post the message on button click. I have put the breakpoint at the controller's action method which should be hit on this button click, but thats not get hitted.
From what i am understanding, i think i am unable to use wallpost.js file in the Scripts folder or the route to call controller's action method is wrong So,there is a problem in reference i think.

The button click should hit the action method but it's not.
PLzz suggest me what should i try.I can provide more code if required.
I was following this article.http://techbrij.com/facebook-wall-posts-comments-knockout-aspnet-webapi

My web-api controller action method is like this----

```
  namespace WebApp.Controllers
  {
   public class WallPostController : ApiController
   {
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
     public HttpResponseMessage PostPost(Post post)
    {
        // post.PostedBy = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        post.PostedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        post.PostedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        // post.UserProfile.UserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedBy");
        ModelState.Remove("post.PostedDate");
        //  ModelState.Remove("post.UserProfile.UserId");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // var usr = db.UserProfile.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == post.PostedBy);
            var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == post.PostedBy);
            var ret = new
            {
                Message = post.Message,
                PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                PostedByName = usr.UserName,
                //PostedByAvatar = imgFolder + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(usr.AvatarExt) ? defaultAvatar : post.PostedBy + "." + post.UserProfile.AvatarExt),
                PostedByAvatar = db.Users.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == post.PostedBy),
                PostedDate = post.PostedDate,
                PostId = post.PostId
                //  UserId = usr.UserId
            };
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, ret);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = post.PostId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

I don't know why its not working. it was working fine when i was using simple membership.now, i want to use it with aspnet identity.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to track down the culprit yourself and/or provide us with a minimal repro. The code in your question itself is not nearly enough for us to reproduce your issue without resorting to guessing what the rest of your code looks like. Put yourself in our shoes: we *only* have your question text to go on.

Comment: PS. The first thing to debug, from the sound of it, would be the network traffic. Are calls to your API going out from your page at all? If they are, there's a problem server/networking side. if they aren't, there's a problem client side.

Comment: @Jeroen Sir,what sort of extra information should i provide bcoz i am unable to track what is going on plzz help

Comment: Specifically, I don't *know* what you should provide, that's the whole point. More generically though, you should provide any code needed to reproduce the issue (see "[mcve]" for guidance). If you don't know how to minimize the code, you can always resort to [bifurcation a.k.a. binary-search-debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/181223/40625)).

Comment: check in chrome, developer tools in network tab if there is any request going at all, you mentioned 404, if there is one, check on which request is it and what is its url, if its wrong -> correct knockout, if its correct, then there must bu sth with your setup, try making request in a simpler way, if there is no request, then its knockout binding

Comment: also put a js breakpoint in your addComment method, it will let you know if knockout is calling ti at all, if it does then its again not knockout issue at all :)

Comment: @mikus in developer tools the message which i saw is----Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404(Not Found) and the url which i am seeing is-----http://localhost:2994/api/WallPost?_=1446887918566 and just below that there is another message------ Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined at line wallpost.js: 95 and at line wallpost.js: 115 Sorry for late reply

Comment: ok, so you have everything :P knockout works, now in knockout model, addPost method you create a request with the link you mentioned, now why you get 404 on it is a different story, maybe you try GET on post METHOD, maybe the api is incorrectly configured or not working, try to access it in other way, test method first, then work on ko. And then the second error is most likely the error callback on your ajax call being implemented inorrectly in wallpost.js